# ajax actionlink and href undefined

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

Check the following code: it's working fine.

```
@Html.SideMenuActionLink
    (
     "<i class=\"icon-windows\"></i>" + item.SourceConnectorsName,  
     new { ConnectorID = item.SourceConnectorsId, Action = "Main",
     controller = "Configuration" },                               
     new { @class = "menuLink" }                                     
     )    


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.menuLink').click(function () {
        history.pushState(null, "Configuration", this.href);
        $('#configurationpanel').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now, I'm doing (almost) the same with an @Ajax.ActionLink:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Connection", "Connection", 
     "Configuration", 
      new { connectorID = Model.SourceConnectorsId }, 
       new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result", OnSuccess = "pushState" })

<script type="text/javascript">
function pushState() 
{
    alert this.href;
}
</script>
```

Problem: this.href is undefined. I can't manage to find why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
function pushState(ev) 
{
    var element = $(ev.target);
    alert(element.attr("href"));
}
</script>
```

Comment: info: when you click on the ajax link, it displays 5 lines in the partial view... and the alert dialogbox is displayed... 5 times. It looks like the object manipulated in the function PushState is the content of the ajax link, not the ajax link itself.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onsuccess(v=vs.118).aspx : Gets or sets the JavaScript function to call after the page is successfully updated. So the link is not available anymore when we're in inside Onsuccess. The real question is how do I rewrite the url (pushstate) when I click on an ajax ActionLink url (like for html.actionlink)?

Comment: And finally I gave up Ajax.ActionLink and used html.ActionLink instead